# glob finds the same file 10 times

Tags: python, glob

Why does the `recursive=True` lead to finding the same file 10 times.

```
>>> for g in glob.glob("/home/result/test/**/**/**/*.xml", recursive=True):
...   if "testsystems" in g:
...     print(f"{g}")
... 
/home/result/test/foo/bar/test_results/testsystems.xml
/home/result/test/foo/bar/test_results/testsystems.xml
/home/result/test/foo/bar/test_results/testsystems.xml
/home/result/test/foo/bar/test_results/testsystems.xml
/home/result/test/foo/bar/test_results/testsystems.xml
/home/result/test/foo/bar/test_results/testsystems.xml
/home/result/test/foo/bar/test_results/testsystems.xml
/home/result/test/foo/bar/test_results/testsystems.xml
/home/result/test/foo/bar/test_results/testsystems.xml
/home/result/test/foo/bar/test_results/testsystems.xml
```

According to the docs I expected to need to use `recursive=True` to support `**`.

> If recursive is true, the pattern “**” will match any files and zero or more directories, subdirectories and symbolic links to directories. If the pattern is followed by an os.sep or os.altsep then files will not match.

source: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/glob.html

I understand now that I should either use

```
glob.glob("/home/result/test/**/*.xml", recursive=True)
```

or to get the expected result

```
glob.glob("/home/result/test/**/**/**/*.xml")
```

My main question is why does `glob.glob("/home/result/test/**/**/**/*.xml", recursive=True)` lead to duplicated files? And why is it 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are these 10 matches:

```
   **                    **                    **
 1 foo/bar/test_results  -                     -
 2 foo/bar               test_results          -
 3 foo/bar               -                     test_results
 4 foo                   bar/test_results      -
 5 foo                   bar                   test_results
 6 foo                   -                     bar/test_results
 7 -                     foo/bar/test_results  -
 8 -                     foo/bar               test_results
 9 -                     foo                   bar/test_results
10 -                     -                     foo/bar/test_results
```

In all 10 cases, `*.xml` of course just matches the file in the matched folder.

The `**/**/**` is not doing what you think it is - it's matching any number of subdirectories (due to the `recursive` option) three times, resulting in the 10 matches. Just `/home/result/test/**/*.xml` with `recursive=True` would do.